# Atomic reads in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I keep finding information about write atomicity, but not reads. Are reads always atomic? For example I pass a read-only query to populate an array with append() by querying multiple different documents. Basically, am I guaranteed to receive a "snapshot" with no writes after the query started appearing in the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you read from multiple documents in the same query it's possible for one of those reads to see a write and another one not to.